# How to show odd data in first column and even data in second column in JSP?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I have to show data into table form. But the problem is that I have to show odd data in first column and even data in second column. Also, the items are a Map.

```
<table>
<c:forEach items="${myMap}"
    var="subcategory" varStatus="status">
    <c:if test="${status.count % 2 != 0 }">
        <tr>
            <td>${subcategory.value}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${status.count  % 2 == 0 }">
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>${subcategory.value}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

This is the nearest I've been and it is printing the data in newline instead of same columns. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. Adding a rowspan worked. I have no idea why. I need to take a step back and think about it but it works.

```
<table style="width: 100%">
<c:forEach items="${myMap}" var="subcategory" varStatus="status">
    <tr>
        <c:if test="${status.index % 2 == 0}">
            <td rowspan="2">${subcategory.value}</td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${status.index %2 != 0}">
            <td>${subcategory.value}</td>
        </c:if>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your map into an array, and iterate over this array every two values, and print two values at each iteration.

```
<c:set var="mapToList" value="${myMap.values().toArray()}"/>
<table>
<c:forEach items="${mapToList}" var="item" step="2" varStatus="status">
   <tr>
      <td>${mapToList[status.index]}</td>
      <c:if test="${!status.last}">
         <td>${mapToList[status.index+1]}</td>
      </c:if>
   </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but the items are a map and they can't be get using an index. I've updated my question to mention that it is a map.

Comment: I've updated the answer so that it applies to a Map.